# Solving an eigenvalue problem for 2nd order linear differential operator in a half-infinity square

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem, eigenfunctions

I'm trying to solve the eigenvalue problem

$$(1+x^2+y^2)\left[(1+x^2)\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+(1+y^2)\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}+2xy \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y}+2x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+2y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right]=\lambda f$$
in the region $$(1,\infty)\times(1,\infty)$$ with Dirichlet boundary condition $$f=0$$ in the frontier. I suppose that the problem can be numerically treated but I don't know how to do it. I need some help.

Comment: I would suggest adding a little context explaining your familiarity with PDE'S, what you have tried, etc.

Comment: where does this problem come from?

Comment: This problem comes from a quantum system consisting on interacting particles in a trap with strongly infinite repulsive Delta interaction. I tried by taking the finite region (1,L)x(1,L) and then using a Fourier basis. But that did not work.